# open chrome-devtools:// URL from script/command line, NOT via copy paste

Tags: node.js, linux, google-chrome, chromium

In order to automate running and debugging node.js applications the debug URL needs to be opened from a script; eg.:

`chromium "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9230/9229"&`

If I copy paste the URL in chromium is working fine.
however as I have stated this step needs to be automated.

How to open an URL of the form `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html` in chromium/google-chrome from script or command line (Linux)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if your goal is just to have this automated for you, or if you want to figure out a way to script this yourself.

That said, there is a package on NPM called `inspect-process` that automates the process of opening DevTools windows. ([Github](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/inspect-process)). It serves as a replacement on the command-line for `node`. e.g.:

`inspect myScript.js` instead of `node myScript.js`

and it automatically opens up a DevTools window.

If you needed to script this process yourself you could likely use code from that package as well.

Comment: Update (2017): inspect-process [does not work with current versions of node](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/inspect-process/issues/52)

Comment: Still works with LTS (6.11 as of right now), but not with >=8.1.3 according to the link

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this doesn't appear to be possible.  I did find [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0wQOfl-UEAk) bug report in the Chrome forums.

The only solution I was able to find was to use AppleScript as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/979678/134947), but you said Linux so that won't be of much help to you.